# React/JS/TS - Mapping dynamic data to a table duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```js
  const keys = data.getUser.keys;

  console.log(keys)

  for(let i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
    var keyNickname = keys[i]['nickname'];
    var keyExchange = keys[i]['exchange'];
    var keyLivenet = keys[i]['livenet'];

  console.log(keyNickname)
 
  const createRow = (
    rowId: number, 
    keyNickname: string, 
    keyExchange: string, 
    keyLivenet: string,
  ) => ({
    cells: [
      { content: `${keyNickname}`, key: `${rowId}` },
      { content: `${keyExchange}`, key: `${rowId}` },
      { content: `${keyLivenet}`, key: `${rowId}` },
    ],
  });

  var rows = keys.map((a: number) => 
    createRow(a, keys[i]['nickname'], keys[i]['exchange'], keys[i]['livenet'])
  );  
}
```

[image: ate]

I'm so close yet so far. I'm just unsure how to properly map the data to the three rows!

Any assistance would be awesome, I'm trying to learn the hard way (and I have been.) though, I would love to solve this so I can move onto create other tables throughout the application.

EDIT: full page as requested:

```js
  const headSet = ['Nickname', 'Exchange', 'Livenet'];

  const head = {
    cells: headSet.map(headSet => ({
      key: headSet,
      content: headSet,
      shouldTruncate: true,
      isSortable: true,
    })),
  };

  const keys = data.getUser.keys;

  console.log(keys)

  for(let i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
    var keyNickname = keys[i]['nickname'];
    var keyExchange = keys[i]['exchange'];
    var keyLivenet = keys[i]['livenet'];

  console.log(keyNickname)
 
  const createRow = (
    rowId: number, 
    keyNickname: string, 
    keyExchange: string, 
    keyLivenet: string,
  ) => ({
    cells: [
      { content: `${keyNickname}`, key: `${rowId}` },
      { content: `${keyExchange}`, key: `${rowId}` },
      { content: `${keyLivenet}`, key: `${rowId}` },
    ],
  });

  var rows = keys.map((a: number) => 
    createRow(a, keys[i]['nickname'], keys[i]['exchange'], keys[i]['livenet'])
  );  
}
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <TopNavigation height={60} isFixed={true}>
        <TopNav />
      </TopNavigation>
      <Content>
      <LeftSidebar width={240} isFixed={true}>
        <SideBar />
      </LeftSidebar>
        <Main>
          <div
            style={{
              marginLeft: 40, 
              marginRight: 40,
            }}
          >
            <PageHeader 
              actions={actionsContent}
            >        
              Connections
            </PageHeader> 

            <DynamicTable
              head={head}
              rows={rows}
              defaultPage={1}
              loadingSpinnerSize="large"
              isLoading={false}
              isFixedSize
              defaultSortKey="term"
              defaultSortOrder="ASC"
              onSort={() => console.log('onSort')}
              onSetPage={() => console.log('onSetPage')}
              rowsPerPage={!keys.length ? 10 : undefined}
            />  
          </div>
        </Main>
      </Content>
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export default Keys;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing bad arguments to your map function.  A cleaner way would be this:

```
var rows = keys.map((key: any, i: number) => 
  createRow(i, key.nickname, key.exchange, key.livenet)
);
```

`Array.prototype.map` takes a function with two arguments.  The first is each element of the array as it is iterated over.  The second is the index of the element in the array.

In your code, you're A) missing the first argument, and B) mistaking 'a' for 'i' in your function when dealing with the index.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation Bill! This indeed did solve it and help me understand more of this mumbo jumbo :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the full source code for this page?   This is tagged as react, but you aren't including any JSX, so I'm not sure if you meant to. I put an example below, but I have no idea of the structure of the data you imported.

```
const keys = data.getUser.keys
   
function TodosList(keys){

const renderRow = () => {
    return keys.map(function(key, i){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{key.keyNickname}</td>
                <td>{key.keyExchange}</td>
                <td>{key.keyLivenet}</td>
            </tr>
             )
         })
    }

return(
    <div><h3>Key List?</h3>
    <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Heading 1</th>
                <th>Heading 2</th>
                <th>Heading 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {renderRow()}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
)
}

export default TodosList
```